# Write a program that receives the customer date of birth in the format (dd-mm-yyyy)

Tags: c#

question :
Famous Insurance company has a requirement to calculate the age of their customer based on the date of birth received as a string from the user.
Write a program that receives the customer date of birth in the format (dd-mm-yyyy).
Pass this value to a method, 'calculateAge' which returns the calculated age. Keep the method 'static'.
Method to implement:
public static int calculateAge(string dateOfBirth)
Sample Input :
Enter the date of birth (dd-mm-yyyy): 22-10-1984
Sample Output:
35

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DateEx1              //DO NOT CHANGE the namespace name
{
    public class Program       //DO NOT CHANGE the class name
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)    //DO NOT CHANGE the 'Main' method signature
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the date of birth (dd-mm-yyyy): ");
            //Implement code here
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            string  birth = calculateAge(s);
            Console.WriteLine(birth);
        }

        public static int calculateAge(string dateOfBirth)
        {
            //Implement code here
            int age = 0;  
            string s = dateOfBirth
            age = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year - s.Year);  
            if (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < s.DayOfYear)  
            age = age - 1;  

            return age; 

        }


    }
}
```

I am new to C# and on line 25 I am getting the following error:

> error CS1061: Type `string' does not contain a definition for`Year' and no extension method `Year' of type`string' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Can anyone please check this code and tell all the mistakes in this code?

Comment: you have to use `DateTime.TryParse` to get it as a `DateTime` type.

Comment: Better to use Timespan here I think.  If you just subtract the year part, you're treating someone born Jan 1 and Dec 31 as the same age, but in may the Jan 1 person will be 30 while the Dec 31 person is still 29 for several more months

Answer (score 4):

I see this:

```
string s = dateOfBirth;
```

and this:

```
s.Year
```

and this:

```
s.DayOfYear
```

We see on the first line that `s` is a **string**. In order to use the properties on the later two lines, you need to define `s` as a **DateTime**:

```
DateTime s = dateOfBirth;
```

**This will still give you a different error**, but since this looks like a learning situation I'll let you work out how to solve the new error on your own.

Comment: Unhandled Exception:                                                            
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.  I am not able to understand this exception can anyone please help.

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid datetime" seems clear enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this would ensure that string was not recognized error won't occur.

```
using System.Globalization;
string format="dd-mm-yyyy";
DateTime date=DateTime.ParseExact(sdate,format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int birth=calculateAge(s);
```

Comment: Adding this would ensure that string was not recognized error won't occur.