# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. Converting string to DateTime

Tags: c#

I need to convert a `string` to a `DateTime` format in the following code. But I am encountering the following error. How can I solve this?

Unhandled Exception:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
public static int calculateAge(string dateOfBirth)
{
    // Implement code here
    int age = 0;  
    DateTime s = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfBirth, "D", null);
    age = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year - s.Year);  
    if (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < s.DayOfYear)  
        age = age - 1;  

    return age; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `DateTime.Parse` instead to allow more formats to work.  Otherwise you need to make sure the string matches the format.  "D" is the long date format so it has to be something like "Monday, June 15, 2009"

Comment: What value is in string dateOfBirth?

Comment: Also don't spam the C# version tags.  They are only needed if the question is specific to a given version and then it would only likely be specific to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DateEx1              //DO NOT CHANGE the namespace name
{
    public class Program       //DO NOT CHANGE the class name
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)    //DO NOT CHANGE the 'Main' method signature
        {

             Console.WriteLine("Enter the date of birth (dd-mm-yyyy) ");
             string dateOfBirth=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(calculateAge(dateOfBirth));

        }

        public static int calculateAge(string dateOfBirth)
        {
            //Implement code here
            //int age;  
            DateTime s = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfBirth, "dd-mm-yyyy",null);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            int year = DateTime.Now.Year;

            int length=dateOfBirth.Length;
            string dcs = dateOfBirth.Substring(6,4);
            string csd=dateOfBirth.Substring(3,2);
            int age2=int.Parse(csd);
            if(age2>=6)
            {
            int age=int.Parse(dcs);
            int age1=(year-1)-age;
            return age1;
            }
            else
            {
                 int age=int.Parse(dcs);
            int age3=(year)-age;
            return age3;
            }
        }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good time to learn to read documentation. We're dealing with the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method. This method has several overloads, but the documentation for the one we care about is here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_

I found that link by searching Google for `C# DateTime.ParseExact()`. I went tot he first search result, and then clicked the first link on the page to find the correct overload.

We see the second argument to that method (where you supplied `"D"`) is a format string. The notes for that argument refer to the Remarks section, where we find this:

> The `format` parameter is a string that contains either a single standard format specifier, or one or more custom format specifiers that define the required format of s. For details about valid formatting codes, see [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netcore-3.1) or [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netcore-3.1).

Follow the link for the Standard Format Strings, and we finally find this information about the "D" format:

> "D"   Long date pattern.    2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Monday, June 15, 2009 (en-US)

This is slightly confusing without the full context on the page, but what this tells you is it's expecting your `dateOfBirth` string to **exactly match** the pattern described by `Monday, June 15, 2009` (`dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy`). Based on the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936413/write-a-program-that-receives-the-customer-date-of-birth-in-the-format-dd-mm-yy), your strings look more like `15-06-2009` (`dd-mm-yyyy`). Those don't match, and that's why you see the error.

To fix this, you need to find a format instead of `"D"` to use with the `ParseExact()` method that will **exactly match** the kind of format used with your input strings.

Again, this looks like a learning situation, so I'll leave it to you to figure that out.